# Cypress get attribute value and assign it to variable in function

Tags: cypress, getattribute

I am trying to get attribute value and return it from a function.
Here is the code that is working and can be used in a normal test class (into the integration folder).

```js
describe('Example shows how to get attribute value.', () => {
    // 'it' is used to create test case. You can add a name of the test case. You can have multiple test cases in one JS class.
    it('Get attribute value.', () => {
        // Cypress is not able to work with new tabs. It is not possible to switch between tabs. Cypress can manipulate the DOM tree, so we can change the element attributes and open the hyperlink in the same browser tab.
        // 'visit()' method is used for navigating to URL address.
        cy.visit('https://demoqa.com/links')
        cy.xpath('//*[@id="simpleLink"]').then(function (element) {
            // 'prop()' method is used to get the attribute value.
            const url = element.prop('href')
            cy.visit(url)
        })
        // Assert URL.
        cy.url().should('include', 'demoqa.com').should('eq', 'https://demoqa.com/');
    })
```

If I use the code that way - everything is working as expected.

But if I want to re-use the code and create a function like this:

```js
// Give a value of the variable to use it for next function.
functionName = 'addAttribute';
// Declare a Cypress child custom command.
Cypress.Commands.add(functionName, { prevSubject: 'element' }, (subject: any, attributeName: string, attributeValue: string) => {
    // Create a try-catch statement. If the function fails - we will recieve the error message.
    try {
        // Create the function steps after this comment.
        cy
            .wrap(subject)
            .invoke('attr', attributeName, attributeValue)
            .should('have.attr', attributeName, attributeValue)
    } catch (error) {
        // Create the error log and show it to the UI. Show the function name, the class where the function is located and catched error.
        let errorMessage = `----------ERROR! It seems that we have an error. Please review the "${functionName}" function from "${__filename.split(__dirname + "/").pop()}" . The error is: ${error}`;
        cy.log(errorMessage);
        console.log(errorMessage);
    }
})
```

The result is 'object' and I am not sure how to process it.
Here is the rest of the code:

```js
describe("'getAttribute' custom child command example.", () => {
    it("example shows how to use 'getAttribute' custom child command.", () => {
        cy.visit('https://demoqa.com/buttons');
        let attributeValue = cy.element('xpath','(//*[contains(text(),"Click Me")])[3]').getAttribute('class');
        cy.log(`The attribute values is: ${attributeValue}`)
    });
});
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

You have to do as below to have a return value:

```
let attributeValue = '';
cy.element('xpath', '(//*[contains(text(),"Click Me")])[3]')
    .getAttribute('class')
    .then((attr) => {
        attributeValue = attr;
    });
cy.log('The attribute values is:' + attributeValue)
```

Comment: When I try to run the code in Cypress I get strange behavior - the browser can;t be manipulated...
https://gifyu.com/image/SSH0u

Comment: `attributeValue` will always be empty at the moment of calling `cy.log` because `then` callback will be executed later (asynchronously)